# Xpage with computed categorized column

Tags: view

I have an xpage that displays a view.  The first column of the underlying view is categorized and displays the author field which displays just fine on the xpage.  However, the author field contains the fully qualified name.  If I change the view column to be @Name([CN]; author), the xpage is no longer categorized.  Instead it displays the common name of the author for each row.  Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried to do exactly the same as you described, however am unable to replicate the issue....

I know it sounds stupid, but when editing the column, did you possibly set the Type: property to standard instead of categorized by accident?

Or possibly checked the "Categorized is flat version 5 or greater" option by accident?

Is this column still categorized in the notes client, and only flat on your xpage?

Comment: I have verified that the column properties are set correctly.  It works in the Notes client but fails in the Xpage.